# How to define gradle "runtime"

Tags: java, gradle

I am using spring boot with gradle. Gradle pack the application to jar with these tasks:

```
bootRepackage {
    mainClass = 'tv.mukamuka.api.Application'
}

jar {
    destinationDir = file(destPath)
    baseName = project.name
}
```

And dependencies as below:

```
compile('com.eclipsesource.j2v8:j2v8_macosx_x86_64:3.1.6')
runtime('com.eclipsesource.j2v8:j2v8_linux_x86_64:3.0.0')
```

However, `bootRepackage` task doesn't build the jar with runtime dependencies. How can I define "runtime" in build?

Comment: Runtime dependencies are not added to the final jar. They're to be provided at runtime by the deployer - e.g. be in the classpath.

Comment: I am really newbee for this. What should I do in this case?

Comment: You should prepare the jar and run it providing the necessary library to classpath: e.g. `java -jar my.jar -cp <classpath>`

Comment: See Gradle user guide: [7.3. Dependency configurations](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html#configurations).

Comment: @Opal that will not work, you cannot use `-jar` and `-cp` options simultaneously. If it's a runnable jar (you use `-jar`) then the classpath is specified in the manifest file of the jar file.

Comment: @Jesper, I didn't know that - thanks!!

Comment: I am not really understand to guide. If I defined a `runtime`, it does't compile anything into the production jar, just a declaration? There isn't any manifest file in the spring boot application. And a furthur question, according to the guide, should I replace `compile` with `testCompile` above?